# Unable to copy default RDS Parameter Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'd like to duplicate a default RDS **Postgres** Parameter Group - e.g. `default.postgres9.4` but the Copy button is grayed out.

How do you duplicate it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Create a new Parameter Group and choose `postgres 9.4` as the Parameter Group Family. Your new group will be a copy of the default group, but you'll be able to modify it.

Also remember to modify your RDS instance to use the new parameter group.