# Cannot modify a default parameter group for binlog_format

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, database-replication

Using RDS Aurora cluster with engine 5.6.mysql_aurora.1.22.2 in AWS with a writer instance(us-east-1a) and a replica instance db.t3.small (us-east-1b).

I'm trying to change the default parameter group for binlog_format from OFF to ROW, but I'm having this error:

```
Error saving: Cannot modify a default parameter group. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: 4571b2e7-02c2-454a-9a21-062a8ffa66a5; Proxy: null)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Probably you should ask [AWS Support](https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/). Stack Overflow is for questions about specific code problems, not cloud service configuration.

Comment: Hummm Thanks @BillKarwin? Can you share where are the rules that can have just code problems in SO, please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45100898/unable-to-copy-default-rds-parameter-group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to change a setting in the parameter groups, you will need to create a new custom parameter group, and then change the binlog_format parameter in there.

Once that's saved, you'll be able to change the RDS instance over to the new parameter group. Rebooting will make the parameter group take affect. Be aware of any downtime from rebooting your instance.

I'm currently trying the same, and have referenced this article: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/enable-binary-logging-aurora/.